# When kill -9 consumer, Can Kafka auto commit offset keep on?

Tags: apache-kafka, consumer

The offset is setted auto commit, and the period is one minute. 
I kill -9 the consumer. Can Kafka auto commit offset keep on?

Comment: Thanks. I want to stop the consumer, and the offset can be auto commited.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `kill -9` (SIGKILL), because consumer won't have any time to react on that signal.

Instead, use `kill -15` (SIGTERM) and add the following code:

```
KafkaConsumer consumer = ...

Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(consumer::close));
```

[Here's the description](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#close()) of the `close` method:

> Close the consumer, waiting for up to the default timeout of 30 seconds for any needed cleanup. If auto-commit is enabled, this will commit the current offsets if possible within the default timeout.

If 30 seconds is too long for you, there is another `close` method that accepts custom timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `kill -9` the process is dead immediately. Whatever hasn't auto-committed already by that point will not.

It's not clear if that's what you want. More detail on the question can yield more detail on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Committing the offset is an operation executed by the Kafka client (it's done using a specific OffsetCommit command in the Kafka protocol). Enabling auto-commit just means that the Kafka client does this operation for you periodically and you don't need to do that explicitly from your application code. So if you kill the consumer there is no offset commit executed anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I want to stop the consumer, and the offset can be auto commited.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean ? If the consumer is stopped (and it's the only one consumer) there is no other entity capable of committing the offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is that you didn’t say which programming language you are using and auto commit is a little different in Java versus the librdkafka clients but in both, if you kill a client ungracefully with kill -9 then the client app is dead and so it has no way of committing offsets. Offsets are always committed by the clients, not the kafka brokers so if you kill -9 a client, the last committed offset will be whatever was committed after the last auto commit interval expired (for librdkafka) or the last call to poll() thereafter (for Java).